# URL not working properly in laravel redirects to object not found

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I am developing a website in laravel which works fine but but there is small issue in my URL's

My url works fine

```
http://localhost:8080/JobScholar/contact
http://localhost:8080/JobScholar/index
```

but when i use a `/` at the end of the url

```
http://localhost:8080/JobScholar/contact/
http://localhost:8080/JobScholar/index/
```

redirects me to

```
http://localhost:8080/index
http://localhost:8080/contact

Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.26 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.7
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        Options -Indexes
        ErrorDocument 403 http://localhost:8080/JobScholar/index
        Options +FollowSymLinks
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

routes

```
 Route::get('/contact', 'ContactPageController@index');
   Route::get('/index', 'HomePageController@index');
```

Comment: I suspect this is due to some misconfiguration on .htaccess. Can you paste your .htaccess content here ?

Comment: Also taking a look at your `DirectoryIndex` setting might be worth a try: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Comment: share your `.htaccess` and `routes` for these ?

Comment: @user2486 .htaccessa nd routes added

Comment: @PSJ .htaccessa nd routes added

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding `RewriteBase /JobScholar/` just after `RewriteEngine On`

Answer (score 0):

I not sure but I think you need to change here in your `.htaccess`

From

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

To

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /JobScholar/$1 [L,R=301]
```